# Шифр Цезаря: организовать выдачу полного перебора

Tags: c#, шифрование

Здравствуйте. Имеется код Шифра Цезаря с ключом, подскажите, как организовать выдачу полного перебора, т.е. чтобы не было ключа и показывало каждый вариант сдвига.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace cezar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 1, key = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите слово,которое нужно зашифровать:");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Введите ключ:");
            key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string s1 = "";
            string alfphabet = "АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯ";
            int m = alfphabet.Length; 

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < alfphabet.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (s[i] == alfphabet[j]) 
                    {
                        int temp = j * n + key;

                        while (temp >= m)
                            temp -= m;

                        s1 = s1 + alfphabet[temp];
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованное слово:" + s1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Каждый вариант сдвига, это по длине слова?

Comment: Имеется алфавит, в данном случае "lfphabet = "АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯ";", нужно чтобы выводил все варианты перестановки, в данном случае 31

Comment: А зачем нужно j*n?

Comment: Это номер буквы
Мне нужно,чтобы вместо "key" был набор цифр от 1 до длины алфавита

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если я вас понял можно попробовать так

```
 static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Введите слово,которое нужно зашифровать:");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        string alfphabet = "АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯ";

        int m = alfphabet.Length;

        List<string> result = new List<string>(); 
        for(int y=1; y<32; y++)
        {
            result.Add(Shift(s, alfphabet, y));
        }

        foreach (var word in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованное слово:" + word);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Shift(string targetWord, string alfphabet , int key)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < targetWord.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < alfphabet.Length; j++)
            {
                if (targetWord[i] == alfphabet[j])
                {
                    int temp = j + key;

                    while (temp >= alfphabet.Length)
                        temp -= alfphabet.Length;

                    result += alfphabet[temp];
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: У меня ругается на "result.Add(Shift(s, alfphabet, y));" ,для не статического поля требуется ссылка на объект.((
Заодно посоветуете с какой литературы начать изучение шарпа?)))

Comment: static в начало метода поставьте(я поправил в ответе). о литературе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Вы меня спасли, теперь обязательно начну изучать,стыдно за такое.

Comment: Если все работает,  вы можете принять ответ и отметить как правильный